# Assigning elements to a lists within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, iterable

I am running Python3.6 and am working with lists which contain other lists within it.

```
list_array = [[1,0,1,0,2,2],
              [1,1,2,0,1,2],
              [2,2,2,1,0,1]]
```

I would like to modify the list called list_array be deleting all the entries with value 2 within the sub lists.

The code I used for this is

```
for k in list_array:
    k = [x for x in k if x!=2]
```

However, this code doesn't modify list_array.

Why isn't it possible to replace the elements in the lists within list_array this way?

Comment: You're explicitly creating a *new* list object, not modifying the one that's referenced by `list_array`.

Comment: `list_array = [[j for j in i if j !=2] for i in list_array]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates a new list every time, and erase the previous one.

At the last iteration you should get this:

```
k = [1, 0, 1]
```

Instead, a list comprehension works fine:

```
list_array = [[x for x in sublist if x != 2] for sublist in list_array]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

If you want to write it with an explicit for loop, it could be done like this:

```
new_list_array = list()
for sublist in list_array:
    new_list_array.append([x for x in sublist if x != 2])
```

Comment: NB. The list comprehension creates a brand new list. The existing list might still be alive, but unmodified.

Comment: @quamrana True, thus the redefinition of `list_array` to replace the initial list with the new one. Hope it will be clear for the OP with those 2 NB.

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a new list instead of assigning to the old one. You can fix this by adding an assignment using `k[:] =`, like this:

```
for k in list_array:
    k[:] = [x for x in k if x!=2]
```

Comment: nice one @Jonas noted :)

Comment: NB This answer also works even if there is another variable which references, say, `list_array[0]`. This other variable will also see any changes.

Comment: Thanks @jonas. There are 2 ways to delete the entries with value 2 from the sub lists. The first is the method suggested by Jonas, the other uses list comprehension; 

    `list_array = [[x for x in sublist if x != 2] for sublist in list_array]`

Which method is faster, and could you please tell me why it is?

Comment: @Isaac Same speed for both. Jonas iterates on list_array and then on k. It's O(n²). The list comprehension does the same thing. Basically, the list comprehension is a way to do for loops in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You are not modifying the old list you can modify it like that

```
list_array = [[1,0,1,0,2,2],[1,1,2,0,1,2],[2,2,2,1,0,1]]
for k in list_array:
   k[:]= [x for x in k if x!=2] 


print(list_array)
```

Comment: I would say that it is quite inefficient. You have an O(n) for loop and a O(n) for the index. In total it's O(n²) for something quite simple that can be achieve in O(n). (without counting the sublist checking and 2 deletion).